# Will the axis scaling to a negative value in threejs affect the front and back sides of the rendering?

Tags: three.js

Just found a uv picture

[image]

As follows I created a triangle, three vertices and corresponding uv coordinates

```js
    let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setAttribute(
      "position",
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(
        new Float32Array([-1.0, 1.0, 0, -1.0, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 0]),
        3
      )
    );
    geometry.setAttribute(
      "uv",
      new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([0.0, 1.0, 0, 0, 1.0, 1.0]), 2)
    );

    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
      geometry,
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("/1.png"),
      })
    );
```

As shown in the figure below, the vertex order is counterclockwise, so the side shooting from the screen to us is the front.

[image]

When I clone a copy and do x-axis scaling -1

```js
    let clonedMesh = mesh.clone(true);
    scene.add(mesh);
    clonedMesh.scale.set(-1, 1, 1);
    clonedMesh.position.x = 2;
    scene.add(clonedMesh);
```

The order becomes clockwise as follows, the front should be shot into the screen, and MeshBasicMaterial only renders the front by default, so it stands to reason that the clonedMesh should not be able to see it.

[image]

Comment: Objects having a world transform with a negative determinant have their front-face winding order reversed. For more info, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12787.